# How to store constant data in DB

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, constants

We have some queries that always return the same result.
For example, query for retrieving all user roles of our system. The result is constant since server is up.
I'm looking for the best way to store such data.

I think about calling table creating script on server start up.

Or to write stored function which will create and fill a table if it doesn't exist and retrieve data if it does.

May be there are better alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you should look into Materialised views.

Comment: I agree - look into materialized views, and into the different refresh options.